# How to find that the following set is connected and compact or not?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, complex-analysis, compactness, connectedness

Let $U$ denote the set of all $n\times n$ matrices $A$ with complex entries such that $A$ is unitary. Then $U$, as a topological subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ is,

1. Compact, but not connected.
2. Connected, but not compact.
3. Connected and compact.
4. Neither connected nor compact.

I know what the terms are but I am really not getting the idea how to solve this. Please help.

Comment: For the compactness, not that we are considering a problem in some finite dimensional vector space. So  compactness is equivalent to bounded and closed. Also, since every norm on this space is equivalent, choose your favourite one.

Comment: I am sorry but I could not understand ''every norm on this space is equivalent'' and how does this specify the answer?

Comment: Hint: consider the application $f(U):=U^{*}U$. What can you tell us about $f$ and $f^{-1}(\text{Id})$?